# Argument order in rethinking::map translation of a dnorm() prior

Tags: r

I'm working with the [rethinking](https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking) package to build a gaussian model. But I'm a bit confused about the argument order in the `rethinking::map()` translation of `dnorm()`.

As you know, `dnorm()` takes three arguments: `(x, mean = 0, sd = 1)`. But in the rethinking textbook and documentation pages all the examples follow this structure: `dnorm(0, 10)`.

Normally R would interpret this as `dnorm(x = 0, mean = 10, sd = 1)`. But in this example model:

```
m.X <- map(
    alist(
        x ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),
        mu <- a,
        a ~ dnorm(0, 10),
        sigma ~ dnorm(0, 10)
    ), 
    data = d
)
```

The `a` (and `sigma`) prior is meant to reflect `mean = 0` and `sd = 10`.

I just want to make sure that the `map` translation of `dnorm()`is effectively `a ~ dnorm(a, mean = 0, sd = 10)` and not `a ~ dnorm(x = 0, mean = 10, sd = 1)`.

Thanks in advance for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually emailed the author of the rethinking package (and textbook) and I just received a reply!

> Hi, [emehex]. Right, the 'a' moves into the first position inside the function.

So `a ~ dnorm(0, 10)` inside a `map()` function **is** translated to:

```
dnorm(a, mean = 0, sd = 10)
```

And the prior can be visualized with this line of code:

```
curve(dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 10), from = -100, to = 100)
```